# TCPDF: Writing multiple images after eachother using writeHTML renders images in a "staircase" shape instead of in a straight line

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I'm using the PHP class TCPDF's writeHTML method for creating a PDF document. It works great and seems to cover what I need, but when I try to create multiple images in a straight line using HTML  elements in a sequence the images are not rendered in the straight line that I expect. Instead, the position of every sequential image is increased (or decreased in some cases) by a few pixels on the y axis, hence making the sequence of images look like a "staircase":

What I expect (every x is a picture):

```
x x x
```

What I get:

```
x
 x
  x
```

Sometimes I get it the other way around:

```
  x
 x
x
```

The HTML markup looks like this:

```
<img src="x.png"><img src="x.png"><img src="x.png"><img src="x.png">
```

HTML does not normally behave this way and I have not found any solutions by Googling. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered trying to put it in a table?

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <img src="x.png">
   </td>
   <td>
     <img src="x.png">
   </td>
   <td>
     <img src="x.png">
   </td>
   <td>
     <img src="x.png">
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much!

I actually briefly thought of this myself but I didn't think the table would be slim enough height-wise, because I need several of these image sequences. Worked like a charm though so thanks again.