# Displaying images in a row with TCPDF and PHP?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to display 3 images in a row using TCPDF from my PHP script. This is what I do:

1. I create some HTML which contains the img.
2. I am using TCPDFs writeHTML function to write the HTML to a file.
3. When I check the created file, the images are not next to each other, each one is a bit below the previous. It looks like stairs.

To see whats going on I debugged the script and copied the HTML string I give as param to the writeHTML function into a HTML file and opened it in a browser. It looks exactly the way I want in a browser. ONly the created PDF seems to be messed up.

This is the HTML:

```
<table> 
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td width="100"> 
               <img width="75" height="75" style="float: left;" src="...">
            </td> 
            <td width="200"> 
                <h2> FOOBAR </h2> 
                <p>
                    <!--Those 3 are the problem -->
                    <img width="30" src="...">
                    <img width="30" src="...">
                    <img width="30" src="...">
                </p> 
             </td> 
          </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am calling TCPDF like this:

```
$pdf->writeHTML($myHtmlFromAboveInAString, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Any ideas what might be wrong? I tried removing the p, doesnt change a thing.

Thanks!

**NOTE:** I just found the answer myself! Each image has to be in another tables column, like showh here: [TCPDF: Writing multiple images after eachother using writeHTML renders images in a "staircase" shape instead of in a straight line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747262/tcpdf-writing-multiple-images-after-eachother-using-writehtml-renders-images-in)

Comment: In your php script, are you using the same default margins that are always used in each of the TCPDF examples? That could be your problem if so